# How to draw with screen pixels

Tags: android, screen, coordinates

I'm developing an android "radar" in which I will show a gps coordinates in my android screen. So I have to convert the latitude and longitude to the pixels (x, y) of the device screen. To do that I though in take the center of the screen like (0, 0) and transform the coordinates of (lat, lng) to my screen pixels (x, y).

The problem is that I dont know how to implement this. I think the idea would sucess but I dont know how the screen works, the pixel coordinates, etc.

Any tips pls?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android supports many different screen orientations.  Because of this, it is **HIGHLY UNADVISED** to EVER use absolute pixels.

The best way to accomplish what you are trying to do is likely through the [OpenGL ES API](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/opengl.html).

If all you want to do is get the "center" of the display, you can use the following:

```
int centX = WindowManager.getDefaultDisplay().getWidth() / 2;
int centY = WindowManager.getDefaultDisplay().getHeight() / 2;
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: but what could be the problem using absolute pixels in this situation? Maybe in another bigger device the radar could be bigger (can show more information)... the only thing I want is to keep the relation between coordinates(lat, lng) and screen pixels(x, y). With openGL what is different? Thanks!